# Component Scanning Performance

Tags: spring, spring-ioc

I'm trying to understand how much time component scanning is adding application context creation.  Currently, it takes ~100 seconds to create the application context and I suspect that component scanning for component definitions is costly.  I have a series of questions as follows:

1. How do I measure the total time spent component scanning?
2. Does the number of base context:component-scan entries impact the search space, I'm assuming component scanning uses PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver to scan each entry on the classpath and then finding classes that match the base-package regex.  Is it more efficient to structure the metadata like:

`<context:component-scan base-package="foo" />
<context:component-scan base-package="bar" />
<context:component-scan base-package="baz" />`

or

`<context:component-scan base-package="foo, bar, baz" />`

3. I'm also assuming that the number of classes that PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver influences component scanning as the check for corresponding component annotations requires the class file to be inspected.  So is it good practice to only keep classes with annotations in a well-defined package to reduce the number classes to inspect?
4. Is there known best practices listed somewhere on what considerations to make in the design to get the most optimal component scanning performance?

Answer (score 0):

Auto scan classes requires to scan all classes in the specified package(s) and can take a long time. If in your package almost all classes are defined as Bean then can use single component scan.

If there are some packages where classes are defined as Bean, then definitely multiple component scan of only that packages should define to reduce the auto scan time.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="foo" />
<context:component-scan base-package="bar" />
<context:component-scan base-package="baz" />
```

Else all beans define in spring configuration instead of Auto scan, but it can increase large size of your file.

Comment: In addiction to this, you could also include/exclude annotations depending on you context. For example, on Spring MVC context only include @*Controller beans.

Comment: I think the gist of Mhod's post is confine PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver search space by trying only keep spring managed beans in the packages corresponding to base package to reduce ASM class scanning.  This makes sense to me.